# create an AVI file

Tags: php, apache-flex, avi

I have got set of images with whom I'll play animation like in powerpoint. Now i need to export that animation to avi, mpeg, mov format using either flex or php. Please tell me if there any solution that will work out for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).  I think it can do what you're looking for (among its many various features).

Comment: You'll have to dig into the documentation... but I'm pretty sure that it provides conversions between (from and to) FLV (flash video) and many other formats (eg mpg, avi, etc).  I also think it will allow you to manipulate individual frames of movie files (like mpegs) -- thus allowing you to sequence a series of images together into a single movie.